# Gradle returns Task 'grails-create-controller' not found

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle

I created grails3.0 project by the command 'grails create-app book' and imported to IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2 as a gradle project.

IntelliJ IDEA seems to recognise the project is grails-gradle project, because right-clicking the 'controller' folder shows 'Grails Controller' in 'New' menu.

But the result is the error saying;

> Task 'grails-create-controller' not found in root project 'book'

IntelliJ's Gradle window does not have any grails-gradle Tasks.

Instructions in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-gradle-project-with-grails-integration.html do not help.

I want to know how to get the grails-tasks available as of grails3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problem with IDEA 14.1.2 and Grails.

https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/39757-5998013018389098499

> there is a bug in IntelliJ 14.1.2 (latest stable). I upgraded and run configuration functionality, including ability to debug, is broken.
>
> From IntelliJ support:
> This appears to be a bug in Grails plugin https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139566 . The fix will be included in the next IDEA EAP update (available at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP ) and IDEA 14.1.3 version.